# Max selectable count for "CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL" gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I created a Gridview with **CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL** in Android.

Everything's working well. But as per requirements, I have to set a limit for selectable items. Let's say, max selectable items limit for the gridview is 3 items. After limit is reached, user cannot select anymore and will show a message.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getCheckedItemCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemCount%28%29) method to check the count on gridview's item select listener and check if count greater than max value

> **public int getCheckedItemCount ()**
>
> Returns the number of items currently selected. This will only be
>   valid if the choice mode is not CHOICE_MODE_NONE (default).

Comment: Thanks **random**. I already used like this, 
Where I am stacking is how not to able to select anymore.

Comment: Were you able to get desired results? Can you point out the issue with this approach?

Comment: My problem is. After I validated max value, I don't know how to disable selecting. Sorry for my unperfected comment.

Comment: Can't you just change checbox's state in gridview i.e. uncheck it and notify change for that particular item if condition is met?

Comment: Oh yes, That's a great idea. I'll try it. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deselect the current item in a multiple Choice gridview, you can use the following in the `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` of the `GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener`:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        if(gridView.getCheckedItemCount() > numberOfSelectionsAllowed ){                       
            gridView.setItemChecked(position, false);                       
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below ways for multiple selection and can use samples also:

1. https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter
2. https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/
3. https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser
4. https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick